# How to distribute gtest tests execution using Incredibuild?

Tags: googletest, incredibuild

IncrediBuild states about new tests distribution feature. How to use it?

How to distribute gtest tests execution using Incredibuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cd <test_dir>`

`xgconsole /test=gtest /command="<the_test.exe>"`

This causes to launch the exe tests on multiple nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sire if this is still relevant but IncrediBuild has an official unit testing solution so please refer to the following link:
https://docs.incredibuild.com/win/latest/windows/ibtestconsole_interface.html?Highlight=gtest

As you can see, there is a new dedicated command - ibtestconsole in order to invoke the tests.